# NullPointerException when starting a second instance of a Kafka streams

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

When I start a second instance of app a NPE is emitted.

```
11:54:16.042 [zgsolucoes-zeroglosa-nucleo-stream-6802b25b-521e-4f67-b5fe-c18269bcad32-StreamThread-3] ERROR o.a.k.s.p.internals.StreamThread - stream-thread [zgsolucoes-zeroglosa-nucleo-stream-6802b25b-521e-4f67-b5fe-c18269bcad32-StreamThread-3] Error caught during partition assignment, will abort the current process and re-throw at the end of rebalance
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.<init>(StreamTask.java:186)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.<init>(StreamTask.java:115)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread$TaskCreator.createTask(StreamThread.java:352)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread$TaskCreator.createTask(StreamThread.java:310)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread$AbstractTaskCreator.createTasks(StreamThread.java:295)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.TaskManager.addNewActiveTasks(TaskManager.java:160)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.TaskManager.createTasks(TaskManager.java:120)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamsRebalanceListener.onPartitionsAssigned(StreamsRebalanceListener.java:77)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.invokePartitionsAssigned(ConsumerCoordinator.java:278)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.onJoinComplete(ConsumerCoordinator.java:419)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.joinGroupIfNeeded(AbstractCoordinator.java:439)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.ensureActiveGroup(AbstractCoordinator.java:358)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.poll(ConsumerCoordinator.java:490)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.updateAssignmentMetadataIfNeeded(KafkaConsumer.java:1275)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1241)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1216)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.pollRequests(StreamThread.java:853)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce(StreamThread.java:753)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:697)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:670)
```

All topics that are consumed and produced has 10 partitions

In StreamTask:185:

partition = zeroglosanucleo.public.sistema_financeiro-4

topology.sourcesByTopic = zeroglosanucleo.public.fibodefinicaomotivoglosa -> {SourceNode@8815} "KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000036:
    topics:     [zeroglosanucleo.public.fibodefinicaomotivoglosa]
"

The first instance work normally.

Comment: What version are you using and can you include your configuration?

Comment: Apparently the error happens only when one of the instances is running inside the docker, running outside the docker works perfectly

Comment: That's interesting. I didn't realize you were running in docker.  I might dig into this some and try and reproduce it.  Off the top of my head, I don't see why this should happen.

Comment: Can you share your `Topology` code? Can it be that you run the same topology with same `application.id` but _different_ input topics?